# Doctrine2 - How to persist the order of a collection?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Docrine2 entities, I have a "list" entity, with a manytomany relationship with "item".

I need to manipulate and save the order of the items in the list.  I can't figure out how to accomplish this using Doctrine2.  What I want is a joiner table that looks something like:

```
list_item
=========
list_id
item_id
sort_order
```

All I can find is this outdated to-do item: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-213

Can I accomplish this using Doctrine?  Or is there some other way I should be going about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an exerpt from [this docs section](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional), that answers your question:

> Real many-to-many associations are less common. [...] Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes.